# Focus on the top of pop up using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new with AngularJS. I have a problem with pop up in AngularJS. When I open a pop up in first time, I scroll to the bottom. After that, I re-open that pop up, it still stay at the bottom but I want it stay at the top. Can you suggest solution for me to solve that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post the relevant code here along with the description of the issue. also if possible replicate the issue on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver: thanks for giving comments. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $anchorScroll in the function that shows the popup like this

```
$scope.openPopup = function() {
  // set the hash to the id of
  // an element at the top of your popup to scroll to.
  $location.hash('hash');

  $anchorScroll();
};
```

You can find more info on the angular api [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed it :D